# por que el servidor me da error 500 en laravel?

Tags: laravel, hosting, error500

tengo un problema al intentar subir un proyecto de laravel a mi hosting (sin cpanel) prové subir una pagina basica sin usar laravel y funciona bien pero al intentar subir algo de laravel me da error 500. hice las pruebas con 2 proyectos diferentes desarrollados con laravel, les muestro como esta alojado y lo que configure para que vean que puedo estar haciendo mal. en el archivo index.php puse

```
require __DIR__.'/../negocio/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../negocio/bootstrap/app.php';
```

y en app/Providers/appServiceProvider.php en la funcion boot agregue

```
 public function boot()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('./../public_html');
     });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recuerda que error 500 es error de código, primero depura y ve viendo si algo falta, un **;** o un **.** para descartar detalles

Comment: estuve investigando más y aparentemente el servicio de hosting de don web no permite que funcionen archivos por fuera de la carpeta public_html eso explicaría por que en hostinger si funciona la página que probé. de todas formas me voy a poner en contacto con el servicio técnico para más información

Comment: un buen consejo es revisar la versión de php que sea igual que tiene el hosting con tu proyecto, eso puede genera el hosting ,otra opcion puede consulta esta soluccion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server/53201601#53201601